# Directory structure for using git with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

I"m going to have to re-organize my directory/folder structure in order to use git with Eclipse, since repo's are not supposed to be located within the workspace.

Being a git newbie I'd like some confirmation that my intended structure makes sense before I start re-organizing and init'ing repos.

My current workspace includes an Android project, a GAE/J project, some common code shared between them.   Aside from some 3rd party libraries, my projects are closely related so I'm going to put them into a single repo.

Here is my proposed structure:

```
root_dir/
  workspace/
    .metadata
  .git               (<--- main git repo for my projects)
  GAE_Project/
    .project
    src/war/etc.
  Android_prject/
    .project
    src/bin/etc.
  Shared_Code_Project/
    .project
    src/etc.
  3rd_Party_Lib_Project/
    .git             (<--- has its own repo)
    .project
    src/bin/etc.
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that "main git repo"?

Comment: My 'main' git repo will be for my 3 projects, which are closely related, so I often make changes that involve code across all three.

Comment: The workspace isn't supposed to be in a repo either. The workspace frequently contains machine-specific information in addition to information about the projects it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Based your proposed structure, it would seem that all the projects under `workspace` is in one repository. Your proposed structure is fine with one caveat that I can see. You may have to ignore the third party project because it is located under `workspace` (which is the `Git` repository).

`Eclipse` projects do not necessarily have to be located within the workspace directory. It can be located anywhere on your system. It may be better to place the third party projects in a different directory.

Comment: I figured I would 'git add' the relevant parts of the 3 main projects to my main git repository, and git would simply ignore the rest because it wasn't added?  Does this make git slower - does git scan everything in the git folder?

Comment: In a sense yes, everything under the `workspace` directory will be scanned. The `git add` command means that those files/directory are to be indexed. Files that are not ignored and has not been indexed would be in a pending state. This would make pulls and merges harder.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your repos are outside of your workspace, it doesn't matter where they are relative to the workspace. In your example `root_dir` contains the workspace and your projects, and I wanted to point out that the workspace could be at `/some/random/path` and your projects could be `/at/totally/different/path`, it shouldn't matter where they are relative to each other.

I keep my local repos in `~/dev/git/` in unix and `/c/dev/git` in Windows.

I keep my workspaces wherever Eclipse wants me to keep them, which is the first directory it pops up for me, sometimes `~/Documents/workspace`, or `%USERDIR%\workspace`. Usually I don't even know where my workspace is, and it doesn't really matter, because the important and interesting part is where my code is.

Comment: Yeah, now I realize that that way of doing it is better, but I've always kept my projects in my workspace folder - somehow it just seemed logical to do that.  But I disagree with your statement that the relative locations don't matter - it is clear from what I've read that you are not supposed to have repos in or beneath your workspace directory.

Comment: The statements 1: "relative location of workspace and local repos shouldn't matter" and 2: "repos shouldn't be under workspace" are both true and completely independent from each other. So I don't understand what you disagree with.

Comment: I'm staring at your comment and not understanding it.  For my statement#2, I'm describing a relative location of repo & workspace that should be avoided - so their  relative locations do matter.  What am I missing?

Comment: I had that feeling with your sentence ;-) Now I see what you mean. What I meant is, as long as your repos are outside of your workspace, it doesn't matter where they are relative to the workspace. In your example `root_dir` contains the workspace and your projects, and I wanted to point out that the workspace could be at `/some/random/path` and your projects could be `/at/totally/different/path`

Comment: Oh, OK, now I understand.  And I agree that that turns out to be a better way to do it.